# NotifyDataSetChanged() isn't showing the updated list

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I get correct objects in filtered list in publishResults() function  but the filtered list is not displayed on the screen after filtering.
Following is the code for CityAdapter class inhereted from ArrayAdapter class.
IT seems like notifyDataSetChanged() isn't working?
Please inform why list is not displaying.What's wrong in the code.

```
import...
public class CityListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<City> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<City> cities;
    private ArrayList<City> filtered_list;

    public CityListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<City>cities) {
        super(context, resource, cities);
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.adapter_view,parent,false);


            holder.box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        City city = getItem(position) ;
        holder.name.setText(city.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
    private class Holder {
        CheckBox box;
        TextView name;


    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new CityFilter();
    }



    private class CityFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            filtered_list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length()!= 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
                    if (cities.get(i).getName().contains(constraint)) {
                        filtered_list.add(cities.get(i));
                        showMessage(cities.get(i).getName() + "added");
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = filtered_list;
            results.count = filtered_list.size();


            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered_list = (ArrayList<City>) results.values;
            int size =filtered_list.size();
            showMessage("Data set changed"+String.format("%d", size));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged in activity/fragment after text change list.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a full list of items in the very beginning (i.e. in the constructor) assigned to the filtered list; so that they can have the entire list when there is no filtering of results (empty search) and that occurs whenever you instantiate the adapter.

```
public CityListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<City>cities) {
    super(context, resource, cities);
    this.cities = cities;
    this.filtered_list = cities; // <<<<< Change here
}
```

*Side Note*

Also override `getCount()` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when reaching the end of the list on scroll whenever the original list size not equal to the filtered list size.

As the original list is `cities`, when you make filtering, its size will shrink down, so you need only to get the filtered list size not the original list size  to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So add this to the adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filtered_list.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Can you please explain why list should be full at the beginning? How does notifyDataSetChanged() function works?

Comment: @Hizafa nice to hear.. The list must be full because the `getFilter()` is automatically called when you instantiate an instance of this adapter, and then `performFiltering()`, `publishResults()` will be called accordingly... in  `performFiltering()`: the `constraint.length()!= 0` won't met, so you'll return an empty list and deliver it to `publishResults()` ... please hit the tick mark at the left to accept the answer .. thank you